# how to use set_interval in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've found the following code:

```
def set_interval(func, sec): 
    def func_wrapper():
        set_interval(func, sec) 
        func()  
    t = threading.Timer(sec, func_wrapper)
    t.start()
    return t
```

I want to schedule one function and refresh it automatically.
To do this I've prepared the following code:

```
import threading

def doSomething():
    print 'test'

def set_interval(func, sec): 
    def func_wrapper():
        set_interval(func, sec) 
        func()  
    t = threading.Timer(sec, func_wrapper)
    t.start()
    return t


func = doSomething()
set_interval(func, 5)
```

But it doesn't work, after every 5 seconds the console returns

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing in the *result* of calling `doSomething()`. Pass in the function *without* calling it:

```
set_interval(doSomething, 5)
```

In Python, functions are just objects, just like strings or lists or integers. You can pass them around just the same.

You probably want to store the returned thread object, so you can later on stop the thread again:

```
t = set_interval(doSomething, 5)
# ...
t.stop()
```

Comment: One question, what if I'd like to use a function with arguments ? can I do something like set_interval(doSomething('test'), 5) ?

Comment: asking because receiving the same error once changed

Comment: @python_beg22: the `set_interval()` function calls `func()`, without arguments. You could use a lambda to pass in arguments, or a `functools.partial` object. Example: `set_interval(lambda: doSomething('test'), 5)` would pass in the lambda as `func`, and each time it is called, it in turn calls `doSomething('test')`. Or use `import functools`, then `set_interval(partial(doSomething, 'test'), 5)`, which pretty much does the same thing.

Comment: @python_beg22: the other option is to teach `set_interval()` about passing along arguments. You'd have to change the definition to accept `*args` and `**kwargs` catch-all parameters, and to pass those on the `func()` call, replacing that with `func(*args, **kwargs)`. That way you can then use arbitrary extra arguments to `set_interval()` which would all be passed on to the calls to `func()`.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

That's because `doSomething` doesn't have an explicit  return. So what's stored in `func` is of `NoneType`.

You can directly do 
    `setInterval(dosomething, 5)`